# FedEx Characters limit in Address Streetlines

Tags: php, fedex

I am integrating FedEx API but there are 35 characters limitation in the address of shipper and recipient. Almost in every case address length is more than 35 characters.

Here is sample FedEx code for shipper in PHP:

```
$shipper = array(
    'Contact' => array(
        'PersonName' => 'Sender Name',
        'CompanyName' => 'Sender Company Name',
        'PhoneNumber' => '1234567890'
    ),
    'Address' => array(
        'StreetLines' => '1 SENDER STREET',
        'City' => 'PUNE',
        'StateOrProvinceCode' => 'MH',
        'PostalCode' => '411011',
        'CountryCode' => 'IN',
        'CountryName' => 'INDIA'
    )
);
```

For StreetLines, there is limit of 35 characters. FedEx is not considering the character after 35 characters.

Comment: You'll get more helpful answers if you explain more of your problem. For example, are you storing the address locally? That will tell if want to truncate before sending to FedEx or if you just want to truncate user submissions. Also, can't you just submit the whole string to FedEx and let them take care of the truncation if that's what they do?

Comment: @pjmorse If I understand the OP correctly, the address he's got is longer than 35 chars, but Fedex API only takes the first 35 chars, so he's asking what to do about passing the address to Fedex and getting Fedex to deliver the package to the correct address.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution for this. Just pass the 'StreetLines' like this:

```
'StreetLines' => array('1 SENDER STREET', 'temp road')
```

Each value will contain <=35 characters. Like this you can push more values also.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer.  This is just a sanity check based on the API documentation details found by searching the FedExWebServicesDeveloperGuide_v2014.pdf for the term "StreetLines".

Page 42 specifies for the Sender Information Address:
  "Address:  StreetLines: two StreetLines elements are allowed"

page 137:  Pickup Service example shows 3 StreetLines used

The real kicker is page 167, Address Validation Service which allows 4 lines to be valid!
  "Address/StreetLines (0 to 4 repetitions)"

page 398:  Recipient Information states StreetLines as "Multiple occurrence field" with no reference to how many occurrences are allowed.

The actual printed FedEx Labels I have tested only allow 2 StreeetLines and they are truncated to 35 characters in length.

With 3 StreetLines, the ShipService Request process will return the error:  "Schema validation failed for request."

Answer (score 0):

Correct, you can have multiple occurrences of the 'StreetLines' element.  For shipping I believe the max occurrence is 2.